# clear screen when the file is truncated while using `tail -f`

Tags: bash, tail, gnu-coreutils

I'm using `tail -f` to print the content of a continuously changing file. When the file is truncated it shows up like this:

```
blah (old)..
blah more (old)..
tail: file.out: file truncated
blah..
blah more..
```

This can get messy when I change the file too often so that it becomes hard to see where the file begins/ends. Is there a way to somehow `clear` the screen when the file is truncated so that it would show up like this?

```
tail: file.out: file truncated
blah..
blah more..
```

Comment: Similar but not the same question: [grep - Suppress 'file truncated' messages when using tail - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169054/suppress-file-truncated-messages-when-using-tail)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a `perl` one-liner to filter the output from `tail -f`

e.g.

```
tail -f myfile.txt 2>&1 | perl -ne 'if (/file truncated/) {system 'clear'; print} else {print}'
```

Comment: It's trivial to see that this method will also clear the screen if the content of the file happen to have the text "file truncated".

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old, but another (potentially simpler) solution is:

`watch -n 1 cat myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

tailf myfile.txt

this is the command tailf rather than tail -f

with this command there is no file truncated returned on the screen

Comment: this does not clean the old content from the screen as I wanted. Anyway Benj's answer is working, thanks..

Comment: ye sorry my bad did see the clear initially and then whilst looking into it totally forgot typical end of day error :) glad you have it working as required

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds their way here more than 11 years later, I've written a somewhat more complicated bash script to do what I want (monitoring a log file) based on watching for size changes:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e

FILE="$1"
#TODO verify $FILE is valid

LAST=0
while SIZE="$(stat -c '%s' "$FILE")"; do
  # This will only trigger due to a race condition, since stat would normally fail
  if [ "$event" = "DELETE_SELF" -o "$event" = "MOVE_SELF" ]; then
    echo "Watch interrupted: file moved or deleted" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  # Small files might be overwritten without us ever seeing a smaller size
  # To be safe, just print out everything again since it's not that much
  if [ "$LAST" -le 2048 -o "$SIZE" -lt "$LAST" ]; then
    clear
    LAST=0
  fi
  if [ "$LAST" -lt "$SIZE" ]; then
    # tail -c +N is 1-based!
    tail -c "+$((LAST + 1))" "$FILE" | head -c "$(( SIZE - LAST ))"
    LAST="$SIZE"
  fi
  read event
done < <(inotifywait -qme 'modify,close_write,delete_self,move_self' --format '%e' "$FILE")
```

It requires `inotifywait` from the `inotify-tools` package. Alternatively, the monitored file can be checked periodically with `sleep`. Simply replace the last 2 lines with the following:

```bash
  sleep 1
done
```

When using sleep instead of inotify, missing a truncate becomes more likely since the file size isn't checked immediately after each write. In exchange, there are no requirements beyond coreutils + clear, and many small writes to the monitored file don't cause increased resource usage.

Advantages:

- Unlike `watch`, the file content is not interpreted, and terminal colors remain intact
- Unlike Benj's perl one-liner, the file content itself can not cause a clear

Disadvantages:

- When instantly overwriting a file larger than the 2048 byte threshold, the truncate may go unnoticed. Therefore, this script doesn't work well when monitoring a text file being edited.
- Each write to the file causes one execution of `stat`, `tail` and `head` each

Note:
When using inotifywait, moving or deleting the file will cause the script to exit. Some text editors do this (`vim` for example).

For more discussion on inotifywait, see [this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)